The Flutter Windows application runs in debug mode, but does not launch in release mode
The Flutter Windows application runs in debug mode, but does not launch in release mode. In the windows event viewer it is written that the name of the failed module is: MSVCP140.dll Exception code: 0xc0000005. How can this problem be solved? I'm using Windows 11 and flutter version 3.22.3. The following libraries are included in the project:

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
cloud_firestore: ^4.14.0
msix: ^3.16.7
google_fonts: ^6.2.1
flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1
http: ^1.2.2
flutter_secure_storage: ^9.2.2
fl_chart: ^0.68.0
media_kit: ^1.1.10+1
media_kit_video: ^1.2.4
media_kit_libs_video: ^1.0.4
image_picker: ^1.1.2
intl: ^0.19.0
permission_handler: ^11.3.1
animated_toggle_switch: ^0.8.3
pdf: ^3.11.1
printing: ^5.13.2
share_plus: ^10.0.2

How can this problem be solved?
